# SonarQube LOC analysis limit

Tags: sonarqube, sonarqube-ops

I'm about to use SonarQube on big projects and have been searching for info about LOC limit for analysis and there is no related information on their website. Is there? if it is, what's the limit?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no hard limit, either within a single project or across the instance. However, depending on your infrastructure (e.g. disk space available for the DB) you may run into practical limits.